# Is it correct to use Spring security roles instead of creating multiple subclasses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, uml

In my web application, I'm wondering if it is correct to use Spring security roles instead of creating multiple subclasses, let's take the following example :

[image]

Instead of having 3 different sub classes, I have thought about using only one class instead which is Person, and to distinguish between them using Spring Security Roles, and until now I haven't faced any problem since the only difference between my classes is that some of theme have one or two extra attributes, so in some cases these attributes will be null, concerning the services and pages that each one can access, Spring Security is doing a great job. So I'm wondering if it's the right way to do it? and if I will face any problem if I work this way? how should I represent this in UML ?
I hope i have been clear enough.
Thank you

> **Note:** I'm asking this question because even if it's working, I have to defend it in front of the "jury"

Comment: Without seeing the Spring Security class it will be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Spring security class? it's just a many to many with roles that's all and with an association class "UserRoles"

Comment: Why don't you want to subclass from Person? What's wrong with that?

Comment: much lesser code to write, the question is why use subclasses?

Comment: Just one idea from the top of my head - this approach may be bad in case you have an application with huge amount of users (and if you have not only 3 roles, but maybe 10) stored in database, and each time you need to find anything in database, you will make a complicated select request to one big table.

Comment: but this won't be solved in the case of TABLE PER HIERARCHY, and in case of TABLE PER TYPE, there is another problem : SQL Join

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to model roles as subclasses of Person. Look into the Party-PartyRole pattern that allows for flexible role assignment.

Comment: @Geert bellekens, I m not sure that i've understood what you said, did you mean that having subclasses of person is a bad idea ?  And i've searched the pattern you said but I'm.not sure if I have understood it correctly, isn't it like  using Spring security User-UserRole-Role ?

Comment: `User-UserRole-Role` sounds pretty much like the same pattern only specialised in users, where Party-PartyRole is much broader then that.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if its working, great. But if you are programing a web application in JAVA its good to use the Object-Oriented concept.
So what you are doing or thinking its WRONG. Most of the frameworks in java use the MVC Pattern, and if you are not using OO you will have trouble.

MVC /

**Model** - Model represents an object or JAVA POJO carrying data. It can also have logic to update controller if its data changes.

**View** - View represents the visualization of the data that model contains.

**Controller** - Controller acts on both model and view. It controls the data flow into model object and updates the view whenever data changes. It keeps view and model separate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, That's what I'm exactly doing, actually I'm using a MVC framework (grails) everything is fine, but how what I'm doing is breaking the OO concept?

Comment: "I have thought about using only one class instead which is Person". Its wrong. You are removing the Abstraction and Polymorphism.                          1)OOPs makes development and maintenance easier where as in Procedure-oriented programming language it is not easy to manage if code grows as project size grows.
2)OOPs provides data hiding whereas in Procedure-oriented prgramming language a global data can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: These are only "beans", no methods insid them except getters and setters, what the need of these two concepts?